# How to pre-fill an Edit page in Jade template (Node + Express + Jade)

Tags: node.js, express

I have a view page where i listed all products and each products has edit and delete button. I am trying to prefill the input field in edit page to show the data of selected product.

I would like to know how to pre-fill the the edit page with the selected product data.

Code for view page.js,

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const listdata = await sapview.listall();
  const pricedata = listdata.T_PRICE;
  res.render('viewpage', {title: 'Products', data: pricedata})
  // res.send(pricedata)
});
```

Code for viewpage.jade,

```
extends layout

block content
  h1(style='text-align:center')= title
  button(type='submit', onClick='add()') Add a Material
  script.
    function add() {
      window.location.href = '/addpage'
    }
    function edit() {
      window.location.href = '/editpage'
    }
    function removed() {
      window.location.href = '/removepage'
    }
  br
  br
  -var product = data
  div
  table.table.table-hover(border='1', style='width:100%')
    tr
        th Sl.No
        th Plant
        th Material
        th Currency
        th Rate
        th Price_Unit
        th Cond_Unit
        th Customer
        th Portal User
        th Options
    tbody
      each value in product
        tr
          td(style='text-align:center')
          td(style='text-align:center', id='p_plant')= value.PLANT
          td(style='text-align:left', id='p_material')= value.MATERIAL
          td(style='text-align:left', id='p_currency')= value.CURRENCY
          td(style='text-align:right', id='p_rate')= value.RATE
          td(style='text-align:center', id='p_price_unit')= value.PRICE_UNIT
          td(style='text-align:left', id='p_cond_unit')= value.COND_UNIT
          td(style='text-align:left', id='p_customer')= value.CUSTOMER
          td(style='text-align:left', id='p_portal_user')= value.PORTAL_USER
          td(style='text-align:left')
            ul
              button(type='submit', onClick='edit()') Edit
              button(type='submit', onClick='removed()') Delete
```

Code for edit page.js,

```
router.put('/editpage', 

(req, res) => {
  console.log("Hello", req.body);
  client.connect(() => {
    console.log('Connecting');
    client.invoke("ZSD_CP_PRICE_CHANGE", 
    {P_PLANT: req.body.P_PLANT, 
    P_MATERIAL: req.body.P_MATERIAL, 
    P_CUSTOMER: req.body.P_CUSTOMER,
    P_RATE: req.body.P_RATE,  
    P_CURRENCY: req.body.P_CURRENCY,
    P_PRICE_UNIT: req.body.P_PRICE_UNIT,
    P_COND_UNIT: req.body.P_COND_UNIT,
    P_PORTAL_USER: req.body.P_PORTAL_USER
    },
    (err, result) => {
      console.log('Invoking')
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return err;
      }
      console.log(result);
    });
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Code for edit page.jade,

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  form(action="/editpage" method="PUT")
    label(for='plant') Plant:
    input(placeholder = 'P_PLANT', id='P_PLANT', value='value.PLANT')
    br
    label(for='material') Material:
    input(placeholder = 'P_MATERIAL', id='P_MATERIAL')
    br
    label(for='customer') Customer:
    input(placeholder = 'P_CUSTOMER', id='P_CUSTOMER')
    br
    label(for='rate') Rate:
    input(placeholder = 'P_RATE', id='P_RATE')
    br
    label(for='currency') Currency:
    input(placeholder = 'P_CURRENCY', id='P_CURRENCY')
    br
    label(for='price_unit') Price_Unit:
    input(placeholder = ' P_PRICE_UNIT', id='P_PRICE_UNIT')
    br
    label(for='cond_unit') Cond_Unit:
    input(placeholder = 'P_COND_UNIT', id='P_COND_UNIT')
    br
    label(for='portal_user') Portal_User:
    input(placeholder = 'P_PORTAL_USER', id='P_PORTAL_USER')
    br
    br
    button(type='submit') Save Changes
    br
    br
  button(type='submit', onclick='nav()') Cancel
  script.
    function nav() {
      window.location.href = '/'
    }
```

[image: View page]

[image: Edit page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using value without the quotes. For example

```
input(placeholder = 'P_PLANT', id='P_PLANT', value=PLANT)
```

Comment: value='PLANT' displays the input field with PLANT text. Am expecting it to show the value as APPLE_GREEN

Comment: Notice that you are using with quotes. That makes it a string. Drop the quotes and see if it works

Comment: Ok. That should be possible to sort out. So if it is blank then lets ensure PLANT is not empty. Print it directly anywhere on the page to see if it shows the value. If not then confirm the value is assigned in page context.

Comment: Make sure the render method has the value of PLANT assigned like  res.render('editpage', {title: 'Products', PLANT: 'value of plant'})

Comment: While clicking **edit button** i assigned the **href** to **'/editpage/'+value.PLANT**. (passed the data as url parameters from View page to Edit page). In edit page while rendering, i used res.render('editpage', {plant:req.params.PLANT}) Then am able to pass the **plant** as variable in input field's **value attribute** Thank you